# Cannot install Ioncube on php

Tags: centos, httpd, php.ini, ioncube

I have downloaded Ioncube then using unzip tar and placed it in document root. Then changed the php.ini file..
I did all according to:

> `http://www.howtoforge.com/installation-of-zendoptimizer-and-ioncubeloader-using-lighttpd-on-centos`

Then I restart my httpd & got this error: 
(my httpd was not re-starting initially i was getting error:

```
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

then i used `sudo fuser -k -n tcp 80`
 then i was able to restart..)

After this i checked php -v and got:

```
php -v
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.0.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.0.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

NOTE: php 5.3 is installed correctly using centOS 6.3 machine..

Comment: Please post result of `uname -a`, you are on x86_64 architecture I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that you are trying to use a 32-bit library in a 64-bit environment. You should download and install the 64-bit version of ZendOptimizer and Ioncube.

Comment: i updated the version fro 64 bit and now i'm getting error:
"[root@support ioncube]# php -v
Failed loading /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.0.so:  /usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.0.so: undefined symbol: empty_string
"

Comment: Oh i think im using the wrong ioncube.. sorry.. i get it know